# Chrome browser banned flash plugin, so it caused me to use the jwplayer plugin to prompt ''No suitable players found!''. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: javascript

Chrome browser banned the flash plugin, so it caused me to use the `JWPlayer` plugin to prompt "No suitable players found". How can I solve this problem?

I used another browser to run the code, that's ok.I have downloaded the flash plugin in my computer too. I tried to permit the chrome browser to run the flash plugin, but I found it can't be set up.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Red5 - OFLADemo</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
      'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
      'file':'id',
      'streamer': 'rtmp://xxx/live',
      'controlbar': 'bottom',
      'width': '848',
      'height': '360'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Time to migrate to HTML5 solutions, or hybrid. Give [Video.JS](https://videojs.com/) a try for example.

Comment: I'm surprised "google" browser (I think you mean "chrome" browser) has finally dropped their "built in" (no, it isn't, I know) version of flash

Comment: *I used other browser to run the code* - Flash was killed off years ago, I guess your "other" browser must be some microsoft browser